How to make mathabx scale correcty in tikzposter?
Selfexplanatory code which generates this : 
\documentclass[40pt, a0paper,dvipsnames]{tikzposter}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
\vspace{-.51ex}
 { \centering
 \block{\Huge\vspace{-.001ex}{Abstract} }
 {\huge
 We try to  have mathematical signs of proper size 
 $A \to \{r \in \mathbb R :  \rho(r) >1 \} $ with \texttt{mathabx} in \texttt{tikzposter}
 }
}
\end{document}



The package declares the fonts are only available in fixed sizes, if you give declarations allowing them to be scaled, they scale.
\documentclass[40pt, a0paper,dvipsnames]{tikzposter}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathabx}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
   <-6>   matha5
  <6-7>   matha6
  <7-8>   matha7
  <8-9>   matha8
  <9-10>  matha9
  <10-12> matha10
  <12->   matha12
      }{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
   <-6>   mathb5
  <6-7>   mathb6
  <7-8>   mathb7
  <8-9>   mathb8
  <9-10>  mathb9
  <10-12> mathb10
  <12->   mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <->      mathx10
      }{}


\begin{document}
\vspace{-.51ex}
 { \centering
 \block{\Huge\vspace{-.001ex}{Abstract} }
 {\huge
 We try to  have mathematical signs of proper size 
 $A \to \{r \in \mathbb R :  \rho(r) >1 \} $ with \texttt{mathabx} in \texttt{tikzposter}
 }
}
\end{document}


Thanks. You saved me from typing arrow-tips manually, or using the standard arrow-tips :)

@c.p. I have no idea if that package is still maintained but if it is you could suggest to its maintainer that it adds a [scaled] option or similar that uses these decalarations rather than the current ones (or uses these by default and adds an option to use the old ones for compatibility when needed)
